# Why two serializables do not serialize in settings?

Tags: c#, serialization

I have WinForms app where serialization is used for WF settings. I have one setting using `System.Drawing.Color` -- it works (serializes) without any problem. I also have some settings using `List<X>` where `X` could be `string`, `System.Drawing.Rectangle` -- it also works.

However when I try to use setting of type `List<System.Drawing.Color>`, and then I save settings (with for example all reds) I get in settings file a list of empty color entries. I.e. colors are not serialized.

Why can it be serialized when I have a color (as single instance) and when I put colors inside list they cannot be serialized?

**Update**: this is how I save the data.

```
// single color -- it works
MyApp.Properties.Settings.Default.SinglePenColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
// list of colors -- it does not work, it produces empty color entries in file
MyApp.Properties.Settings.Default.MarkerColors = 
    new [] { System.Drawing.Color.Red, System.Drawing.Color.Red }.ToList();

MyApp.Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Comment: What kind of serializer you use?

Comment: @eocron, just for the record -- I don't, this is done internally by WF. Anyway, the settings is XML file.

Comment: Can you include code for how you're saving your settings?

Comment: @john, sure, please see the update.

Comment: We can't see what curr_colors is or what the runtime values are. Add classes and debug info or write up a [mcve].